# How to read and write non-standard document properties of word file in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Microsoft Word is offering some default document properties to be set in Word documents.
There is a number of default properties, for which vbscript has constants.
But Word (2011) is offering some more properties, e.g. companyfaxnumber, publishingdate,keywords.

There is a possibility to access the builtin properties by calling

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oWord.Documents.Open(strFilePath)
For Each prop In oWord.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties
    WScript.Echo prop.Name + "::" + oWord.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(prop.Name).Value
Next
```

But how do i find the names of the "custom" properties that are offered by word, but are not present in vbscript as constant?
There is the function

```
Document.CustomDocumentProperties
```

But if i do a listing like the one above, i get properties named info1, info2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too access the Word CustomDocumentProperties, you will need to be able to access the OLE File Property Reader. This expands beyond the normal/simple document properties because it allows you too add custom properties as well.

There is a Tales from the Script article from 2005 detailing the installation and usage of utilizing CustomDocumentProperties within Word -> [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee692828.aspx)

For the download to install the OLE Property Reader DLL, Go -> [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8422)

Here is an example of property set/get once the property read is installed:

```
Const msoPropertyTypeBoolean = 2

Set objFile = CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
objFile.Open("C:\Scripts\New_users.xls")

'Set
'=======================================================================
objFile.CustomProperties.Add "Document Reviewed", msoPropertyTypeBoolean
objFile.Save

'Get
'=======================================================================
Set objProperty = objFile.CustomProperties.Item("Document Reviewed")
wscript.echo objProperty.Value
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Hi recently figured out how to get there myself:

The Word "Frontend Editor" is cheating on the document properties. There is a hard defined set of properties like author,category, keywords etc.
The additional properties offered by the editor are so called custom properties which are defined in an external XML structure inside the docx-container.
So there is no easy vbscript function to modify the values of these custom properties.
Thanks to the web, someone did some hacking and this is the solution for it:

```
Sub WriteCustomCoverProperties(ByRef wordInstance, strProp, strText)
    Dim oCustPart 
    Dim oNode 
    Dim strXPath 

    strProp = Replace(strProp, " ", "") 
    Select Case strProp 
        Case "Abstract" strXPath = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:Abstract[1]" 
        Case "PublishDate" strXPath = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:PublishDate[1]" 
        Case "CompanyAddress" strXPath = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:CompanyAddress[1]" 
        Case "CompanyPhone" strXPath = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:CompanyPhone[1]" 
        Case "CompanyFax" strXPath = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:CompanyFax[1]" 
        Case "CompanyEmail" strXPath = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:CompanyEmail[1]" 
        Case Else 
    Exit Sub 

    End Select 
    Set oCustPart = wordInstance.ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(3) 
    Set oNode = oCustPart.SelectSingleNode(strXPath) 
    oNode.Text = strText 
    Set oCustPart = Nothing 
    Set oNode = Nothing 
End Sub
```

May it be of help =)